# Can't figure out CSS Sticky Footer!

Tags: html, css, sticky-footer

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do you get the footer to stay at the bottom of a Web page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42294/how-do-you-get-the-footer-to-stay-at-the-bottom-of-a-web-page)

Hello,

I can't get my footer to stick to the bottom of my page!!  I have been trying everything and I can't get the sticky html/css code to work

No matter what I do, the footer is offset, or half way up the page... I have tried like 3 different versions of code to make it stick, no luck

could someone please help me??  If someone could please tell me the correct coding

My site is:
http://graves-incorporated.com/test/index.html

Css:
http://graves-incorporated.com/test/p7csslm/p7csslm10.css

Thanks,
Dan
mrlincoln89@hotmail.com

Answer (score 0):

adding position: fixed to your footer usually does the trick(then set bottom: 0 )

something like this:

```
#footer {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

for more information try this link:

[How do you get the footer to stay at the bottom of a Web page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42294/how-do-you-get-the-footer-to-stay-at-the-bottom-of-a-web-page)

Comment: position: fixed will put the footer at the bottom of the page, but it will also not scroll with the rest of the page.  That may be what Dan wants, but the chosen answer on the linked question seems more likely.

Comment: come to think of it we should just flag this as a duplicate

Comment: On my page I can get the footer to go to the bottom with absolute positioning but the footer is offset and if i minimize the browser and scroll down the footer stays half way up the page (over the top of my text)

Answer (score 0):

You may want to take a look [at this site.](http://ryanfait.com/position-fixed-ie6/)

Hope it helps.

Comment: I've tried that site.  It wouldn't work on my page, so I even started with a new blank page and css and still couldn't get it to work.  This is driving me insane haha

Comment: Messing aruond on your site with firebug I was able to have it stick down the bottom with 'position:absolute;bottom:0;left:0'. Not sure how this would fair in IE6 though. I'm guessing not very well, haha.

Comment: I'll give that a shot and roll with it for at least a temporary fix. Thanks!

Comment: I must be stupid, I just tried the bottom 0 left 0 and it still doesn't work for me!! haha What am I doing wrong!?